# Async validation with Formik, Yup and React

Tags: reactjs, formik, yup

I want to make async validation with formik and validationschema with yup but i can't find the example or demo.

Answer (score 43):

```
const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
    username:
        Yup.string()
            .test('checkDuplUsername', 'same name exists', function (value) {
                return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    kn.http({
                        url: `/v1/users/${value}`,
                        method: 'head',
                    }).then(() => {
                        // exists
                        resolve(false)
                    }).catch(() => {
                        // note exists
                        resolve(true)
                    })
                })
            })
})
```

Yup provides asynchronous processing through the test method. 
(kn is my ajax promise function)
have a nice day.

Comment: Any idea on how to do multiple validations for the same field? For example, if the name is required and it must be unique

Comment: @tsinat simply chain it - e.g., `Yup.string.required('Username is required').test(...)`

Comment: Doing this results in the following for me: `Error: Validation test of type: "exists" returned a Promise during a synchronous validate. This test will finish after the validate call has returned`

Comment: you need to return also the `kn.http` or you will loose the async chain

Answer (score 13):

Actually, it can be simplified a bit

```js
const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
    username: Yup.string().test('checkEmailUnique', 'This email is already registered.', value =>
        fetch(`is-email-unique/${email}`).then(async res => {
            const { isEmailUnique } = await res.json()

            return isEmailUnique
        }),
    ),
})
```

Answer (score 9):

##### You can use `async/await` with `yup` custom validator

```js
let field = yup.string().test(
'test-id',
'error message in case of fail',
 async function validateValue(value){
  try{
    
     // validation logic
     return false; // or true as you see fit

  } catch(error){

  }
});
```

return `true` for the values you accept

return `false` for the values you reject

Make sure you always return a boolean, or add a `finally` block if you don't have that guarantees yourself.

Answer (score 4):

For example I am using fake promise, It can be done as follow:

```
  const Schema = yup.object().shape({
      password: yup
   .string()
  .test("validPassword","Password requires one special character",
  function (value) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        if (
          /^[0-9A-Za-z]*[!@#$%^&*()_+\-=\[\]{};':"\\|,.<>\/?][0-9a-zA-Z]*$/.test(
            value
          )
        ) {
          resolve(true);
        } else {
          resolve(false);
        }
      }, 100);
    });
  }
 ),
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to async validate with API call:

```
const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
  username: Yup.string().test('checkDuplUsername', 'same name exists', function (value) {
    if (!value) {
      const isDuplicateExists = await checkDuplicate(value);
      console.log("isDuplicateExists = ", isDuplicateExists);
      return !isDuplicateExists;
    }
    // WHEN THE VALUE IS EMPTY RETURN `true` by default
    return true;
  }),
});

function checkDuplicate(valueToCheck) {
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    let isDuplicateExists;

    // EXECUTE THE API CALL TO CHECK FOR DUPLICATE VALUE
    api.post('url', valueToCheck)
    .then((valueFromAPIResponse) => {
      isDuplicateExists = valueFromAPIResponse; // boolean: true or false
      resolve(isDuplicateExists);
    })
    .catch(() => {
      isDuplicateExists = false;
      resolve(isDuplicateExists);
    })
  });
}
```

Comment: I'm curious to know whether this was tested. One obvious problem to me, before I even attempt to try this, is that you have a ``await`` in a function that's not marked with ``async``. That's already a "compiler" error right there.