# how to wait for one field yup to trigger another reacts

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, yup

how to wait seconds to validate field with yup? I need city code to wait a few seconds because of the state field

```
const schema = yup.object().shape({
 state: yup.number().nullable().required('required'),
 city: yup.number().nullable().required('required')
})
```

Comment: Well you can wait with ``setTimeout`` but not sure if that the best option for you problem. Maybe try some ``async-await``?

Comment: but how can i do async await only in city?

Comment: This is an example using ``promises`` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55811114/async-validation-with-formik-yup-and-react